# bad_cast is not thrown always from dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, casting

I'm facing some issues while using exception handling for `dynamic_cast`. It is not returning `bad_cast` always.

the statement below is **not throwing me bad_cast**, though `d1` is returned `nullptr` and compiler is showing me warning

```
derived *d1 = dynamic_cast <derived *> (&base);
```

but if i try with following statement:

```
derived d1 = dynamic_cast <derived &> (base);
```

then **it will throw std::bad_cast**

Am I missing something in the logic? classes are polymorphic.

Comment: From [this `dynamic_cast` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast): "If the cast fails and new_type is a pointer type, it returns a null pointer of that type. If the cast fails and new_type is a reference type, it throws an exception that matches a handler of type std::bad_cast."

Comment: got it. This point i wa
s missing. This explains lot of things.

Comment: sometimes the answer is only as far away as reading the manual... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is defined that way.

If the new type to be casted to is a pointer the result is a nullptr on error.
If it is a reference it throws an exception.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

> If the cast is successful, dynamic_cast returns a value of type new_type. If the cast fails and new_type is a pointer type, it returns a null pointer of that type. If the cast fails and new_type is a reference type, it throws an exception that matches a handler of type std::bad_cast.

Answer (score 3):

As already answered, this is the defined behavior.

the logic behind this is that when the developer asks the program to convert pointer to another type pointer, you can return null as a valid failure result.

but you can't do it with references. there is no such thing as "null reference" nor can you construct "default reference" and pass it by reference to `dynamic_cast` (as an "out" parameter). basically, if you can't convert a reference to another type of reference, you don't have much to do other than throwing an exception. any other "failure techniques" (such as returning `bool` , error code, null pointers etc.) cannot work with references.

As a side note, I myself used `dynamic_cast` in my works yet I'm not proud of it it at all.  for me, the use of `dynamic_cast` was some sort of defensive programming. usually, If you hold a pointer or a reference to a base class, it makes more sense to use virtual functions to handle derived-class behavior then explicitly go through the pain of manual casing.

Comment: thanks much for the detailed answer. I was simply coding and was going straightforward. This problem made me look things deeply.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior of [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

> If the cast fails and new_type is a pointer type, it returns a null pointer of that type. If the cast fails and new_type is a reference type, it throws an exception that matches a handler of type [std::bad_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast).